# Display 0.3 instead of 10^-0.3 in logarithmic plot

Tags: pgfplots

I have a loglog plot where the ordinate only covers less than a magnitude. pgfplots will display the plot like this:

[image]

It is hard to make out the actual time it takes, it must be somewhere between one and a tenth of a second. Is there some way to label the ordinate with numbers between 0.1 and 1 like in a regular plot?

Comment: 10^(-0.3) is about 0.5, not 0.3

Comment: Use `\begin{loglogaxis}[
        log ticks with fixed point,
    ]`. BTW can you add your code to the question?